# Hash and sign via trapdoors for lattices

Tags: signature, lattice-crypto, trapdoor

Both the papers [GPV'08](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/432.pdf) and [MP'11](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/501.pdf) present trapdoors for lattices that allow to recover $s\in\mathbb{Z}_q^n$ and the error vector $e\in\mathbb{Z}_q^m$ when given $y=As+e$, for $A\in\mathbb{Z}_q^{m\times n}$.

Also, they claim that their constructions allow to construct signatures via the "hash and sign" paradigm. That is, given a random oracle $h:\{0,1\}^*\to \mathbb{Z}^m_q$, to sign a message $M$, the signer computes $$\mathsf{Sign}(\mathsf{td},M)=\mathsf{Invert}(h(M))=(s,e)$$ such that $As+e=h(M)$, where $\mathsf{td}$ is the trapdoor for $A$ and $\mathsf{Invert}$ is the inversion algorithm.

My questions are:

1. Does this means that there are a non-negligible number of words in $\mathbb{Z}_q^m$ that are *decodable*?
2. If so, every word in $\mathbb{Z}_q^m$ is decodable or we need to use a similar technique as in [CFS'01](https://www.iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2001/22480158.pdf), the McEliece based signature, where we need to try to decode $h(M,i)$ (for $i=0,1,2...$) several times, before getting a signature?

Answer (score 6):

1. No: the parameter $m$ and the size $B$ of the coefficients of $(s,e)$ would not be the same in both scenarios. In the first (LWE decryption) the matrix $A$ is high and narrow, which makes the function `strongly injective', and decoding is possible. Most images do *not* have preimages, i.e., only a small fraction of $y$ are decodable, those corresponding to proper encryption. For (SIS) signature the matrix is wide and short, so that most images have *many* preimages. The term *decodable* should not be applied here nevertheless, since, well, the preimage is not unique.
2. No. There is no need to try several times, though care must be taken to avoid `learning attacks' such as [this one](https://cims.nyu.edu/~regev/papers/gghattack.pdf). This is the role of Gaussian sampling.